# Some letters (ü, ä) in file name turning to gibberish after uploading to FTP in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to upload image file to FTP server and filename has western European character.

```
file_name = 'müde_Mäuschen'
```

If I upload this file to FTP it changes letters. File name in FTP becomes `mÃ¼de_MÃ¤uschen`.

Notes:

1. If I upload file to FTP using FileZilla then name works perfectly so FTP server do support this european letters.
2. I'm on Windows 10, Python 3.9.0

Code:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP("Login Details")
path = r'D:\ftp_test'
file_name = 'müde_Mäuschen.jpg'

ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {file_name}", open(path+'\\'+file_name, "rb"))
```

Comment: Tip to get answers faster: Since you already know your problem is only in writing to ftp because of the file name, dumb this down to just that line, and hard code the path to make it copy-paste reproducible for people trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, updated the question. can you tell me what do you mean 'hard code the path'?

Comment: this edit is perfect, good job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the filesystem encoding of the remote system:

```
ftp = FTP('Login Details', encoding='cp1252')
```

Otherwise filenames and directory names will be decoded with the default encoding of the local system.

---

I don't know what encoding the destination system is using, but it looks like it's a Windows machine and cp1252 is a common encoding on Western European Windows machines.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working. I did try 'cp1252' encoding but I was doing it with `ftp.encoding = 'cp1252'`, which doesn't work. any idea why this happens?

Comment: It looks to me as if the `FTP` instance [connects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/11b5045b0ce18fee8cc1023cc516aeb14ebf7bda/Lib/ftplib.py#L120) in its `__init__` method if it can, so setting encoding after initialisation is too late.